# How to point two different domains to the same web application (Apache)

Tags: virtualhost

I have an app: l'et's call it Mickey.

To access the app, I've configured the `vhost` in apache, so that when accessing the third level domain mickey.example.com, the app Mickey is served.

This works.

And this is its configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mickey.example.com
        # ServerAlias Not required

        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mickey.example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/mickey.example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mickey.example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to configure another domain: mickey.example2.com

The end result should be that the Mickey app has to be served when accessed from mickey.example.com and when accessed from mickey.example2.com.

So, basically I have:

1. The same third level domain
2. The same app
3. TWO DIFFERENT second level domains.

## WHAT I DID

### First attempt: configure a DNS `CNAME` alias

As first attemp, I simply added a new DNS record in domain example2.com that pointed to mickey.example.com:

DNS for domain example2.com:

- Type: CNAME
- Host: Mickey
- Points to: mickey.example.com

This didn't worked: after DNS propagation, when I accessed the domain mickey.example.com, the server redirected me to the default domain configured in Apache (that is, let's say, defaultexample.com)

### Second attempt

As I didn't pointed out immediately that it was the server that redirected to defaultexample.com, I changed the DNS record from a CNAME one to an `A` one:

DNS for domain example2.com:

- Type: A
- Host: Mickey
- Points to: 123.456.789.012

Where 123.456.789.012 is the IP of the server that serves Mickey app.

This didn't worked: the server continued to redirect me to defaultexample.com.

At this point I guessed that was the server that redirected me, so I started digging into Vhost configuration (leaving the DNS record as an `A` one, and it is an `A` one while I'm writing this question).

### Third attempt: `ServerAlias` in Apache

As first attempt, I tried to add a `ServerAlias` to the `vhost` that serves mickey.example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mickey.example.com
+       ServerAlias mickey.example2.com

        ServerAdmin mu@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mickey.example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/mickey.example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mickey.example.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This didn't work: Apache continues to redirect me to defaultdomain.com.

### Fourth attempt: A dedicated `vhost`

At this point I created a dedicated `vhost` calling it `mickey.example2.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
-        ServerName mickey.example.com
+        ServerName mickey.example2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mickey.example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/mickey.example.com/log/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/mickey.example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
-        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mickey.example.com
+        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mickey.example2.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I enabled the new `vhost` in Apache and reloaded it:

```
sudo a2ensite mickey.example2.com.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Nothing: accessing mickey.example2.com continues to redirect me to defaultdomain.com

## What to do now?

At this point I don't know how to proceed: I have tried all what I thought should have worked, but it didn't.

Any suggestions?

As told, I need to serve the same exact app both from mickey.example.com and from mickey.example2.com.

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: are you sure your second domain is getting resolved to the same IP address which your first doamin is getting hosted on?

Comment: @ZarehKasparian, yes, I am: I did a traceroute on both domains and both of them end at the same IP, the one of my server.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it!

After many hours of tests and digging in the server, I discovered it was an issue with the Let's Encrypt digital certificate: after a new challenge and a new verification of the third level domain, now all works as expected!